# Mockito returns null when mocking Spring Repository

Tags: spring, junit, nullpointerexception, null, mockito

I'm trying to create a test class for some of my services but I haven't been able to mock my DAOs, which are annotated as seen here:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class TestDAO {

}
```

This is my test class

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class ArchivoTest {

    @Mock
    public TestDAO testDAO;

    @Test
    public void test() {

        System.out.print(testDAO == null);

    }
}
```

When I run the test with JUnit archivoDAO is always null, and I don't know what to do about it or if I'm missing something. I'm a complete noob at mockito, but a half an hour search through google solved nothing, so I guess it's something not that obvious. Thanks in advance

Comment: Post a **complete** minimal example reproducing the problem. By complete, I mean complete. I.e. I must be able to copy and paste the code in my IDE, without any modification, and compile and run it. Without having to guess imports or anything like that.

Comment: code refactored so that it is a minimal example

Comment: You are using a JUnit4 runner with JUnit5 test annotations... Something is probably not going to match there. Either use JUnit4 or JUnit5 but mixing them I wouldn't recommend.

Comment: M Deinum you were right, I've edited my configuration and now it works perfectly. Post it as an actual answer so I can cmark it as correct